# Unable to recursively multiply BigInt beyond a certain number of iterations at compile-time in D

Tags: d, compile-time, bigint, phobos, recursive-templates

I need to get the product of an arbitrary number of variables. The actual number of variables and their values will be known at compile-time, however I cannot hardcode these because they come from reflection done on types at compile-time, using templates.

I can get the product of these into a `BigInt` at runtime just fine, however if I try to do so at compile-time using templates and immutable variables, I can only get the product for a small number of variables before I get a compiler error.

Here is a condensed example that doesn't use type-traits, but suffers from the same issue:

```d
import std.bigint;   // BigInt
import std.stdio;    // writeln

template Product(ulong value) {
    immutable BigInt Product = value;
}

template Product(ulong value, values...) {
    immutable BigInt Product = Product!value * Product!values;
}

immutable BigInt NO_PROBLEM = cast(BigInt)ulong.max * ulong.max * ulong.max;
immutable BigInt ERROR = Product!(ulong.max, ulong.max, ulong.max);

void main() {
    writeln(NO_PROBLEM, " ", ERROR);
}
```

Trying to compile this with `dmd` compiler gives the error message:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/druntime/import/core/cpuid.d(121): Error: static variable `_dataCaches` cannot be read at compile time
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d(200):        called from here: `dataCaches()`
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d(1547):        called from here: `getCacheLimit()`
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d(758):        called from here: `mulInternal(result, cast(const(uint)[])y.data, cast(const(uint)[])x.data)`
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/bigint.d(380):        called from here: `mul(this.data, y.data)`
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/bigint.d(380):        called from here: `this.data.opAssign(mul(this.data, y.data))`
/opt/compiler-explorer/dmd2-nightly/dmd2/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos/std/bigint.d(430):        called from here: `r.opOpAssign(y)`
<source>(9):        called from here: `Product.opBinary(Product)`
<source>(13): Error: template instance `example.Product!(18446744073709551615LU, 18446744073709551615LU, 18446744073709551615LU)` error instantiating
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

I'm quite puzzled by this. At initial glance, it would appear that too much memory is being requested at compile-time (I would understand if there were less heap available during compile-time execution than at runtime), however I'm not sure this is actually the problem, as I can generate the result at compile-time, just not through the recursive template.

Could it be a bug in the Phobos runtime, or an undocumented limitation?
`std.bigint` appears to be designed to be able to produce huge values at compile-time, with lines such as this compiling and executing fine (and bloating the size of the executable!):

```d
immutable BigInt VERY_BIG = BigInt(2) ^^ 10000000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens on the last line of this function:

https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/e0af01c8adf75b164b43832dd7544e297347cf6f/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d#L1824-L1844

It looks like std.bigint is currently not written to work in CTFE in this circumstance. Perhaps simply making the `GC.free` call conditional on `__ctfe` will fix the problem.

As to why it happens with 10 iterations but not 11, the function has a branch which allows performing the calculation for small numbers without dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and probably the answer I'll accept soon. From this info, it seems clear to me that the issue is unlikely from me being a D newbie and is indeed a limitation in the stdlib. By the way, I realise now I used a slightly poor choice of example in my code: the original code I used (not shown) is multiplying different numbers together, leading the error to be triggered in this function instead: https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/e0af01c8adf75b164b43832dd7544e297347cf6f/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d#L1644 It looks like the same kind of issue as you describe, though.

Comment: Apologies, I have since updated my code example to more closely demonstrate the issue in my original code. The updated code sample raises a slightly different error in a different method of the same file, the one i linked in my previous comment (although it still looks memory-related and I suspect your answer broadly remains valid). I think I'm going to raise an issue on the Phobos bug tracker for this.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same general problem - the code is not CTFE-aware, and assumes it will be executed at runtime and not compile-time. Since you have a good use case for this, I would like to encourage you to fix the Phobos module - the modifications shouldn't be too difficult, and should consist of adding some `if (__ctfe)` branches + fallbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your gentle encouragement! As a first point of call, I have written a (presumably failing) test case in a fork of Phobos: https://github.com/saxbophone/phobos/blob/30fd6bb488a6e15419a76e3324c5b8c8ff55895a/std/bigint.d#L2366-L2392
If I can grok the build and test process for Phobos, maybe I'll have a go hacking on it for a fix.